# how to understand what the inverse limit is?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, category-theory

I really can't understand the meaning of inverse limit and even examples of computing it in diffrent cases and I'm looking for some easy(if such a thing exists!!!) for it. 
thanks for any help...

Comment: I highly recommend Section 1.4 of [The Rising Sea](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf).